# DecimalFormat using Turkish Format

Tags: android, number-formatting

My format is

```
DecimalFormat decimalformat = new DecimalFormat("0.00##");
```

But my user is Turkish,Russian etc. They different local. They using my app . Give error look like this
For Turkish ,"10,00"

My Error;

java.lang.NumberFormatException:Invalid Double:"10,00"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have not enough information how do you parse the input, but i suggest you to do it this way:

```
static String parseInput(String input) throws ParseException {

    DecimalFormat dFormat = new DecimalFormat("0.00##");
    Number number         = dFormat.parse(input);
    // double numAsDouble = number.doubleValue();

    return number.toString();
}
```

Not really nice, but you could also try to parse the input by replacing ',':

```
static String parseInputByReplace(String input) throws ParseException {
    DecimalFormat dFormat = new DecimalFormat("0.00##");
    double number = Double.parseDouble(input.replace(',', '.'));
    return dFormat.format(number);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should parse using the culture of the user. `decimal.Parse` will do that. If you use a culture of your own it means you are explicitly "telling" the parser to only use that format.